# How can I use different colours for in-text citations and figure hyper-references in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Consider the following RMarkdown document:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: yes
title: 'Title'
author: 
  - Name
geometry: margin=1in
bibliography: references.bib
csl: something.csl
link-citations: yes
linkcolor: blue
urlcolor: black

header-includes:
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
 \usepackage[all]{hypcap}
---

Lorem ipsum [@reference]

```{r landscape, echo=FALSE,include=TRUE,warning=FALSE,fig.cap="\\label{fig:landscape}Caption"}

knitr::include_graphics("file.png")

```

Referencing to \autoref{fig:landscape}.
````

When I run this sort of document, I see the *same* hyper-linked colour (blue) for both citations (like the `[@reference]` and references to the figure (the `\autoref`).

[image]

[image]

I want to be able to separate the colouring of my references and hyperlinks to figures in the same document (like blue for the Evanno et al., 2005 in the image and red for the Figure 2). How can I do this in RMarkdown? I've tried wrapping the `\autoref{}` in a `\color{red}{\autoref{fig:landscape}}` but this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can follow the technique described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226374/261065) to define a new command for figure referencing.

````
---
title: 'Title'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: yes
author: 
  - Name
geometry: margin=1in
bibliography: reference.bib
link-citations: yes
linkcolor: blue
urlcolor: black
header-includes:
  \newcommand\figref[1]{{\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}\autoref{#1}}}
---

Lorem ipsum [@R-base]

```{r landscape, echo=FALSE,include=TRUE,warning=FALSE,fig.cap="\\label{fig:landscape}Caption"}

plot(1:10)

```

Referencing to \figref{fig:landscape}.
````

---

[image: different color for figure reference]